# How to select a button in selenium webdriver where a user will pass parameter?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

This is my java code

```
package com.ej.zob.modules;

import java.awt.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SetExchange {
public void Execute(String CountryName, String value)
{
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("SET")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.linkText("EXCHANGE RATE")).click();
    //LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[.=\""+CountryName+"\"]/following-sibling::*")).findElement(By.xpath("//input[@maxlength='4']")).sendKeys(value);
    //LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format("//input[@id=%s]",CountryName))).sendKeys(value);
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id,'new_"+CountryName+"_')]")).sendKeys(value);
    //LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'Albania')]")).click();
    LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'setExchangeRate('Afghanistan','AFN')')]")).click();
    WebElement w = LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.id("msg_"+CountryName+"_ALL"));
    LaunchApplication.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(w.getText());
    //LaunchApplication.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals("Exchange Rate Saved Successfully",w.getText());
}
}
```

This is my HTML.

```
<div style="display: table-cell;width:270px" name="cell">
<input id="new_Afghanistan_AFN" type="text" maxlength="4">
<input type="button" value="SET" onclick="setExchangeRate('Afghanistan','AFN')" name="save">
```

Let's look at line no. 7 
      `LaunchApplication.driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick,'setExchangeRate('Afghanistan','AFN')')]")).click();`

In this line, I am finding the element by its attribute and its value.But I want to use String CountryName(Execute method arguments) instead of value setExchangeRate('Afghanistan','AFN')')]". That means the user will pass Country Name from my main method and it should be clicked.Let us suppose if the user passes Afghanistan from the main method the Afghanistan button should be selected.Hope you understand.

Comment: as you can see the findBy arguments take strings as inputs, so you just need to put the string together with your argument in the right form

Comment: so how to do this? Is there any xpath() expression to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method like the following one to generate the locator:

```
public string GetButtonCountryLocator(string countryName, string countryCode)
        {
            string buttonLocator = string.Format("//input[contains(@onclick,'setExchangeRate('{0}','{1}')')]", countryName, countryCode);
            return buttonLocator;
        }
```

The code will be identical in Java.

EDITED:
Java version:

```
public final String GetButtonCountryLocator(String countryName, String countryCode)
{
            String buttonLocator = String.format("//input[contains(@onclick,'setExchangeRate('%1$s','%2$s')')]", countryName, countryCode);
            return buttonLocator;
}
```